# MySQL Query Deletion

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to delete records from tbl_Billing and I want to use LIMIT while performing this function. Please suggest if it's possible using INNER JOIN or LEFT JOIN. The query is below

```
DELETE
FROM tbl_Billing
WHERE `aCreated` > '2011-01-09'
AND `aStatus` ='2'
AND `aUserUnique`
IN (

SELECT aUserUnique
FROM tbl_Users AS user
WHERE user.`aBillingRenew` < date_sub( now( ) , INTERVAL 60 DAY )
AND user.aActive =1
  )
```

Comment: WHERE do you want to put the LIMIT? Is it in the DELETE or in the SELECT ? For a joined result, it becomes unpredictable to specify the exact records that will be returned unless there's som sort of ordering.

Comment: @itsols i want to keep limit in DELETE  not in SELECT.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer. We have to use `EXISTS` instead of the `IN` operator:

```
DELETE
FROM tbl_Billing
WHERE `aCreated` > '2011-01-09'
AND `aStatus` ='2'
AND EXISTS 
( 
  SELECT aUserUnique
  FROM tbl_Users AS users
  WHERE users.`aBillingRenew` < date_sub( now( ) , INTERVAL 60 DAY )
  AND users.aActive ='1'
)
limit 10
```